# Is there a workaround against loss of precision in pgfplots axis?

Tags: pgfplots, formatting

I am generating a bunch of plots automatically using pgfplots. For some datasets the span of data in one axis (y) is relatively small (relative to the absolute value) and therefore pgfplots when printing the numbers in that axis outputs a ridiculous repetition of numbers (see figure, -1.41 repeated 4 times).

[image: repeated numbers in axis]

Of course one option is to increase the formatting precision for the numbers, adding digits. The question is, Can the precision be set automatically by some option in the `axis` options?

This can lead to an unlimited number of necessary digits, which leads to a second question is there an easy way to automatically choose a reference base value and "add" it to the scaling (e.g. `$\cdot 10^8 - 10^7$` instead of `$\cdot 10^7$` in the example).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[]{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot coordinates {
 ( 10, -14136746 )
 ( 72.421875, -14136749 )
 ( 166.054688, -14136829 )
 ( 228.476562, -14137018 )
 ( 290.898438, -14137366 )
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While not being a (La)TeX solution, you could use Python's matplotlib and export to pgf. It allows solutions to both of your questions/issues (adding a fixed value and significant digits). I use this approach for all my plots combined with a makefile, which automatically reruns the Python-scripts on changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a cleaned version of Roald's version (expl3-side). I have made up one command that calculates the precision for the file (to be used before the file is included).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \l__roald_ymax_fp
\fp_new:N \l__roald_ymin_fp
\fp_new:N \l__roald_diff_fp
\fp_new:N \l__roald_nmax_fp
\fp_new:N \l__roald_precision_fp

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_set:Nn { NV }

% From Jake (adapted): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24910/find-a-extremal-value-in-external-data-file-with-pgfplot
\DeclareDocumentCommand { \precisionforfile } { m }
  {
    % max
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \table in {#1} {
        \pgfplotstablevertcat{\concatenated}{\table}
    }
    \pgfplotstablesort[sort~key={1},sort~cmp={float~>}]{\sorted}{\concatenated}
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{1}\of{\sorted}
    \fp_set:NV \l__roald_ymax_fp \pgfplotsretval
    % min
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \table in {#1} {
        \pgfplotstablevertcat{\concatenated}{\table}
    }
    \pgfplotstablesort[sort~key={1},sort~cmp={float~<}]{\sorted}{\concatenated}
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{1}\of{\sorted}
    \fp_set:NV \l__roald_ymin_fp \pgfplotsretval
    % calc
    \fp_set:Nn \l__roald_nmax_fp { ceil ( ln ( abs( \l__roald_ymax_fp ) ) / ln ( 10 ) ) + 1 }
    % Number of digits in the difference
    \fp_set:Nn \l__roald_diff_fp { ceil ( ln ( abs( \l__roald_ymax_fp - \l__roald_ymin_fp ) ) / ln ( 10 ) ) }
    % Calculate the precision
    \fp_set:Nn \l__roald_precision_fp { \l__roald_nmax_fp - \l__roald_diff_fp }
    \def\precision{\fp_to_int:N \l__roald_precision_fp}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{filecontents}{dataA.dat}
    10          -14135746
    72.421875   -14136100
    166.054688  -14136829
    228.476562  -14137018
    290.898438  -14137701
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{dataB.dat}
    10          -14136846
    72.421875   -14136949
    166.054688  -14136829
    228.476562  -14136718
    290.898438  -14136866
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\precisionforfile{dataA.dat}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            zerofill,
            precision=\precision,
            /tikz/.cd,},
        title={dataA.dat, Precision=\precision}]

        \addplot table[] {dataA.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

*Update:* The new version works with coordinate input.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \l__roald_ymax_fp
\fp_new:N \l__roald_ymin_fp
\fp_new:N \l__roald_nmax_fp

\fp_new:N \l_roald_precision_fp

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_split:nnN { nxN }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_set:Nn { Nx }

\DeclareDocumentCommand { \precisionforcoord } { m }
  {
    \fp_zero:N \l__roald_ymin_fp
    \fp_zero:N \l__roald_ymax_fp
    \regex_split:nxN { \( } { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq
    \seq_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
      {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 }
        \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ) } { }
        \regex_split:nxN { \, } { \l_tmpa_tl } \l_tmpb_seq
        \fp_set:Nx \l_tmpa_fp { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 2 } }
        \fp_compare:nT { \l__roald_ymin_fp = 0 } { \fp_gset_eq:NN \l__roald_ymin_fp \l_tmpa_fp }
        \fp_compare:nT { \l__roald_ymax_fp = 0 } { \fp_gset_eq:NN \l__roald_ymax_fp \l_tmpa_fp }
        \fp_compare:nT { \l_tmpa_fp > \l__roald_ymax_fp } { \fp_gset_eq:NN \l__roald_ymax_fp \l_tmpa_fp }
        \fp_compare:nT { \l_tmpa_fp < \l__roald_ymin_fp } { \fp_gset_eq:NN \l__roald_ymin_fp \l_tmpa_fp }
      }
    \fp_set:Nn \l__roald_nmax_fp { ceil ( ln ( abs( \l__roald_ymax_fp ) ) / ln ( 10 ) ) + 1 }
    \fp_set:Nn \l_roald_precision_fp { \l__roald_nmax_fp - ( ceil ( ln ( abs( \l__roald_ymax_fp - \l__roald_ymin_fp ) ) / ln ( 10 ) ) ) }
    \def\precision{\fp_to_int:N \l_roald_precision_fp}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\coordinatesa{
    (10,          -14135746)
    (72.421875,   -14136100)
    (166.054688,  -14136829)
    (228.476562,  -14137018)
    (290.898438,  -14137701)
}

\def\coordinatesb{
    (10,          -14136846)
    (72.421875,   -14136949)
    (166.054688,  -14136829)
    (228.476562,  -14136718)
    (290.898438,  -14136866)
}

\begin{document}
\precisionforcoord{\coordinatesa}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            zerofill,
            precision=\precision,
            /tikz/.cd,},
        title={A, Precision=\precision}]
        \addplot coordinates \coordinatesa;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip2em
\precisionforcoord{\coordinatesb}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            zerofill,
            precision=\precision,
            /tikz/.cd,},
        title={B, Precision=\precision}]
        \addplot coordinates \coordinatesb;
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For the new version you will need an up-to-date expl3 installation (TL17). If you're on an older distro (e.g. TL16) updated to the frozen state you can change `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}` to `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}` and include a `\usepackage{l3regex}`. Note: The latter package will probably be removed from distributions in the future.

---

*Update 2:* I've just introduced a nearly on-the-fly command which replaces your addplot. The only problem is that it includes the axis environment (you cannot add another plot there), because the y labels have to be adjusted as options there.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\fp_new:N \l__roald_ymax_fp
\fp_new:N \l__roald_ymin_fp
\fp_new:N \l__roald_nmax_fp

\fp_new:N \l_roald_precision_fp

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_split:nnN { nxN }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_set:Nn { Nx }

\DeclareDocumentCommand { \precisionforcoord } { m }
  {
    \fp_zero:N \l__roald_ymin_fp
    \fp_zero:N \l__roald_ymax_fp
    \regex_split:nxN { \( } { #1 } \l_tmpa_seq
    \seq_remove_all:Nn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
      {
        \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { ##1 }
        \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { ) } { }
        \regex_split:nxN { \, } { \l_tmpa_tl } \l_tmpb_seq
        \fp_set:Nx \l_tmpa_fp { \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq { 2 } }
        \fp_compare:nT { \l__roald_ymin_fp = 0 } { \fp_gset_eq:NN \l__roald_ymin_fp \l_tmpa_fp }
        \fp_compare:nT { \l__roald_ymax_fp = 0 } { \fp_gset_eq:NN \l__roald_ymax_fp \l_tmpa_fp }
        \fp_compare:nT { \l_tmpa_fp > \l__roald_ymax_fp } { \fp_gset_eq:NN \l__roald_ymax_fp \l_tmpa_fp }
        \fp_compare:nT { \l_tmpa_fp < \l__roald_ymin_fp } { \fp_gset_eq:NN \l__roald_ymin_fp \l_tmpa_fp }
      }
    \fp_set:Nn \l__roald_nmax_fp { ceil ( ln ( abs( \l__roald_ymax_fp ) ) / ln ( 10 ) ) + 1 }
    \fp_set:Nn \l_roald_precision_fp { \l__roald_nmax_fp - ( ceil ( ln ( abs( \l__roald_ymax_fp - \l__roald_ymin_fp ) ) / ln ( 10 ) ) ) }
    \def\precision{\fp_to_int:N \l_roald_precision_fp}
  }
\DeclareDocumentCommand { \axisplot } { O{} m }
  {
    \precisionforcoord{#2}
    \begin{axis}[y~tick~label~style={
            /pgf/number~format/.cd,
            fixed,
            zerofill,
            precision=\precision,
            /tikz/.cd,},#1]
      \addplot coordinates #2;
    \end{axis}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\coordinatesa{
    (10,          -14135746)
    (72.421875,   -14136100)
    (166.054688,  -14136829)
    (228.476562,  -14137018)
    (290.898438,  -14137701)
}

\def\coordinatesb{
    (10,          -14136846)
    (72.421875,   -14136949)
    (166.054688,  -14136829)
    (228.476562,  -14136718)
    (290.898438,  -14136866)
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\axisplot[title={A, Precision=\precision}]{\coordinatesa}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip1em
\begin{tikzpicture}
\axisplot[title={B, Precision=\precision}]{\coordinatesb}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: precision]

Comment: One might even omit the definitions of `\l__roald_ymax_fp` and the minimum version (the pgfplotsretval could be used).

Comment: Would this work for files only ? or can it work for inline tables. (Like the example in the question)

Comment: @alfC I've updated with a version that works for coordinates only.

Comment: I am getting an error `LaTeX error: "kernel/command-not-defined"
! 
! Control sequence \regex_split:nnN undefined.
` with `pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)`. I get the same error with `lualatex`.

Comment: @alfC If your TL16 is fully updated (frozen state) then you need to change the `pgfplots` `compat` setting to `1.14` and have a `\usepackage{l3regex}`.

Comment: I had to use `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{l3regex}` in my TeXLive (from updated Fedora 26). I think it worth using the most compatible version.

Comment: @alfC Did it work then? It should give you the adapted precisions eitherway.

Comment: yes it works very nicely. I mean "posting the most compatible version" (not "using the most compatible version"). Do you think there is way to do this automatically, without predefining the data before the plot? (do it on the fly with the current dataset.)

Comment: @alfC I've introduced a new command, but it is not ideal. A real on-the-fly version is probably impossible as you need to adjust the parental axis environment.

Answer (score 9):

This answer should address question 1.

The precision could be set as axis option by means of `/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=<some value>`.

Here are some examples:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\centering
\foreach \precision in {4,5,6,7}
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=\precision,
title={Precision=\precision}
]
\addplot coordinates {
 ( 10, -14136746 )
 ( 72.421875, -14136749 )
 ( 166.054688, -14136829 )
 ( 228.476562, -14137018 )
 ( 290.898438, -14137366 )
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks, that is fine but is there a way to automatically choose precision based on the data. e.g. some option like `, precision=automatic,`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have an answer for this `:(`

Answer (score 3):

I might have a solution, although the current code is very ugly, because I'm not very familiar with macro's, calculating and storing values.

The code works as follows. It looks at the amount of digits in the largest y value of the data set (`\nmax`). Then it calculates the amount of digits of: `\ymax - \ymin` (`ndiff`). Then the amount of significant digits is given by: `\nmax - \ndiff`.

## Code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}
\usepackage{xparse}

% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197844/rounding-a-number-to-its-hundred
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\ceil}{m}
{
    \fp_eval:n { ceil ( #1 ) }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\logten}[1]
{
    \FPeval\res{ ln( abs(#1) ) / ln( 10 ) }
}

% From Jake: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24910/find-a-extremal-value-in-external-data-file-with-pgfplot
\newcommand{\findmax}[1]{
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \table in {#1} {%
        \pgfplotstablevertcat{\concatenated}{\table}%
    }%
    \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={1},sort cmp={float >}]{\sorted}{\concatenated}%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{1}\of{\sorted}%
    \let\ymax=\pgfplotsretval%
}
\newcommand{\findmin}[1]{
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \table in {#1} {%
        \pgfplotstablevertcat{\concatenated}{\table}%
    }%
    \pgfplotstablesort[sort key={1},sort cmp={float <}]{\sorted}{\concatenated}%
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{1}\of{\sorted}%
    \let\ymin=\pgfplotsretval%
}

\begin{filecontents}{dataA.dat}
    10          -14135746
    72.421875   -14136100
    166.054688  -14136829
    228.476562  -14137018
    290.898438  -14137701
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{dataB.dat}
    10          -14136846
    72.421875   -14136949
    166.054688  -14136829
    228.476562  -14136718
    290.898438  -14136866
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\findmax{dataA.dat}
\findmin{dataA.dat}

% number of digits in \ymax
\logten{\ymax}
\def\nmax{\ceil{\res}}
\FPeval{\nmax}{(nmax) + 1}

% Number of digits in the difference
\FPeval{\diff}{(\ymax) - (\ymin)}%   
\logten{\diff}
\def\ndiff{\ceil{\res}}

% Calculate the precision
\FPeval\precision{clip(nmax - ndiff)}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        y tick label style={
            /pgf/number format/.cd,
            fixed,
            zerofill,
            precision=\precision,
            /tikz/.cd,},
        title={dataA.dat, Precision=\precision}]

        \addplot table[] {dataA.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Result for both data sets

[image: dataA] [image: dataB]

## Bugs

The code works for one data set, but if I run the function `\findmin` or `\findmax` on a second data set in the same document, it sometimes returns an old `\ymin` or `\ymax`.

Comment: Don't mix syntax: use either expl3 or fp. But expl should suffice.

Comment: @TeXnician I got bits and pieces from here and there and don't understand them well enough to rewrite them.

Comment: I have written up another answer with a cleaned-up version (credits to you). Works great (+1) ;)