# How to restore ticklabels

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to answer to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124180/how-to-control-pgfplots-axis-power-of-ten-scalling-to-select-exponents-multiple/124185#124185) question. I almost got a solution but I missed one last thing. The code is the following:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgflibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usepackage{fp}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfplotsdrawaxis}{\pgfplots@draw@axis}
\makeatother

\pgfplotsset{after end axis/.append code={
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\maxexponent}{round(log10(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}))}
  \pgfmathparse{-3*floor(\maxexponent/3)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\exponent}{\pgfmathresult}
  \pgfplotsset{scaled y ticks=base 10:\exponent}
  \pgfplotsdrawaxis}}

\newenvironment{myaxis}[1][]
{\begin{axis}[yticklabels={},scaled y ticks=false,#1]}
{\end{axis}}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[fixed point arithmetic]
    \begin{myaxis}
      \addplot {1000000*x^2};
    \end{myaxis}    
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I use the `after end axis` option to store the maximum y value of the plot and to get the right exponent for the scaling, then I redraw the axes. In order to not having superposition of the default ticks and new ticks (different scaling), I define a new environment without y tick labels. But then I don't know how to restore them... the result so far is the following:

[image]

I get the right scaling (the default for this function is 10^7) but I can't print y tick labels...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I came to a solution. I use the `\axisdefaultticklabel` macro that `pgfplots` uses to draw the tick labels redefining it as empty and restoring it to its initial value in the `after end axis`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgflibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usepackage{fp}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pgfplotsdrawaxis}{\pgfplots@draw@axis}
\makeatother

\pgfplotsset{after end axis/.append code={
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\maxexponent}{round(log10(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}))}
  \pgfmathparse{-3*floor(\maxexponent/3)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\exponent}{\pgfmathresult}
  \def\axisdefaultticklabel{$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$}
  \pgfplotsset{scaled y ticks=base 10:\exponent}
  \pgfplotsdrawaxis}}

\newenvironment{myaxis}[1][]
{\begin{axis}[scaled y ticks=false,#1]%
    \def\axisdefaultticklabel{}}
{\end{axis}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[fixed point arithmetic]
\begin{myaxis}
\addplot {1000*x^2};
\end{myaxis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```