# How can I round numbers relative to their order of magnitude?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This is a question which came up in the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183227/1537 .

Suppose we have a *sequence* of numbers for which we know that they are the log of some quantity. Now I want to compute exp of the input value and format the result in some cool way. How can I avoid rounding inaccuracies such that it fits *all* numbers in the sequence?

Let us assume that the problem is stated as

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

% use \newcommand (not \def), so the one (and only)
% argument can be specified in {} (and not in []) brackets
\newcommand{\mynum}[1]{
  % =\pgfmathparse{e^\tick}\pgfmathresult : ! Dimension too large. ; - use exp(x)
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}% else dimension too large!
  \pgfmathparse{exp(#1)}%
  \pgfmathfloattofixed\pgfmathresult
  \pgfmathresult
}

\message{^^J}

\mynum{-0.69316}

\mynum{0.0}

\mynum{1.60942}

\mynum{2.30258}

\mynum{3.912}

\mynum{4.60516}

\mynum{6.21458}

\mynum{6.90775}

\mynum{8.51717}

\mynum{9.21033}

\mynum{10.81975}

\mynum{11.51291}
\end{document}
```

Ideally, each number would be rounded to a relative accuracy of, say, 3 digits - but relative to the number as such.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The key is to employ `/pgf/number format/fixed relative` which determines the accuracy relative to the current number and generates a fixed-point number as result.

This return value makes use of `\pgfmathprintnumberto[..., verbatim]` to stress that the resulting macro `\tmp` contains a standard fixed point number which is *not* formatted (i.e. does not contain math-mode stuff like `{,}`) and can be used as input to other number formatters. The original question in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183227/1537 relied on siunitx.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

% use \newcommand (not \def), so the one (and only)
% argument can be specified in {} (and not in []) brackets
\newcommand{\mynum}[1]{
  % =\pgfmathparse{e^\tick}\pgfmathresult : ! Dimension too large. ; - use exp(x)
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}% else dimension too large!
  \pgfmathparse{exp(#1)}%
  \pgfmathfloattofixed\pgfmathresult
  \message{exp(#1) = \pgfmathresult^^J}%
  \pgfmathprintnumberto[
    % it is rounded relative to its (individual!) order of
    % magnitude:
    fixed relative,
    % ... and with three digits relative to its order of
    % magnitude. This should avoid rounding problems
    % since it is applied to each tick number
    % individually.
    precision=3,
    verbatim,
  ]{\pgfmathresult}{\tmp}%
  \message{fixed realtive=\tmp^^J}%
  \tmp
}

\message{^^J}

\mynum{-0.69316}

\mynum{0.0}

\mynum{1.60942}

\mynum{2.30258}

\mynum{3.912}

\mynum{4.60516}

\mynum{6.21458}

\mynum{6.90775}

\mynum{8.51717}

\mynum{9.21033}

\mynum{10.81975}

\mynum{11.51291}
\end{document}
```

The console output is

```
exp(-0.69316) = 0.50012
fixed realtive=0.5
exp(0.0) = 1.0000000000
fixed realtive=1
exp(1.60942) = 4.99974000000000
fixed realtive=5
exp(2.30258) = 10.000000000
fixed realtive=10
exp(3.912) = 49.9974000000000
fixed realtive=50
exp(4.60516) = 100.00000000
fixed realtive=100
exp(6.21458) = 499.974000000000
fixed realtive=500
exp(6.90775) = 1000.0000000
fixed realtive=1000
exp(8.51717) = 4999.74000000000
fixed realtive=5000
exp(9.21033) = 10000.000000
fixed realtive=10000
exp(10.81975) = 49997.4000000000
fixed realtive=50000
exp(11.51291) = 100000.00000
fixed realtive=100000
```

Comment: Minor typo in first word. (Not worth editing on its own for sure!)

Comment: Thanks; I've corrected it. Feel free to edit any typos, I appreciate the effort.